# How to merge a keySet of a Map with each List Element : Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a List of Maps like List(map1, map2, map3)
And another Map(String, String) say.. Map(String,String) specified as outer in below example :

I want the keys of the Map named 'outer' as key and map it to m1 map within the List. That means i want a 1-to-1 mapping between keys of outer map with the maps in the List

```
val m1 = Map("id"->"int", "firstname"->"String", "lastname"->"String")
val m2 = Map("Address"->"String", "Salary"->"Int")
val m3 = Map("Mobile" -> "Int", "email"->"String", "landline"->"int")

val listMap = List(m1,m2,m3)

val outer = Map("test1" -> "location_1", "test2" -> "location_2", "test3" -> "location_3")

val res = outer.map(out => listMap.map(inner => (out._1,inner)))

res.foreach(println)
```

This generated the Output as : (which i don't want)

```
List((test1,Map(id -> int, firstname -> String, lastname -> String)), (test1,Map(Address -> String, Salary -> Int)), (test1,Map(Mobile -> Int, email -> String, landline -> int)))
List((test2,Map(id -> int, firstname -> String, lastname -> String)), (test2,Map(Address -> String, Salary -> Int)), (test2,Map(Mobile -> Int, email -> String, landline -> int)))
List((test3,Map(id -> int, firstname -> String, lastname -> String)), (test3,Map(Address -> String, Salary -> Int)), (test3,Map(Mobile -> Int, email -> String, landline -> int)))
res0: Unit = ()
```

What i want is :

```
Map(test1 -> map1, test2 -> map2, test3 -> map3)
```

How can i achieve this ..??

Answer (score 0):

Maps don't retain order, so I don't think this is possible with the setup you have. How about this?:

```
val output: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = listMap.zipWithIndex
  .map { case (map, i) => s"test${i + 1}" -> map } (collection.breakOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by :

```
val newMap = outer.zipWithIndex.map{
      x => (x._1._1, listMap.zipWithIndex.apply(x._2)._1)
    }

    newMap.map(println)
```

Comment: Not guaranteed to work in all cases. `Map` has no inherent order so `zipWithIndex()` will work differently with Maps of different sizes and/or key values. The fact that it works for this example is more or less an accident.

Comment: Is there a better way than which can guarantee that..?

Comment: One option might be to use `ListMap` instead of `Map`. ListMap maintains an order of its elements. From the [Scala docs page](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html): "... traversal methods visit key-value pairs in the order whey were first inserted."